# Пара уточнений о "скелетной реализации" Блоха

Tags: java

Я пересмотрел свои знания на эту тему, и вот мое изложение:

Мы можем объединить преимущества абстрактных классов и интерфейсов, сопроводив каждый представляемый вами нетривиальный интерфейс абстрактным классом с наброском(скелетом, то есть реализованными методами) реализации(skeletal implementation class). Интерфейс по-прежнему будет определять тип, а вся работа по его воплощению ляжет на скелетную реализацию.
Скелетная реализация должна имплементировать только один интерфейс, который специально сделан для скелетной реализации(то есть предполагается, что некоторые методы должны реализовываться одинаково, а некоторые по-разному). По соглашению, скелетные реализации носят названия вида AbstractInterface, где Interface — это имя реализуемого ими интерфейса. Примеры — AbstractCollection, AbstractList, AbstractMap,AbstractSet;

Учитывая факт того, что интерфейсы имеют кл. слово default получается, что модель блоха нужна для тех случаев, когда нужны изменяемые(не final, как в интерфейсах) переменные, которые взаимодействуют в реализованных в абстрактном классе методах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Физические ограничения

Да, необходимость объявлять нестатичные поля является наиболее веской и однозначной причиной для использования абстрактного класса для скелетной реалзиации.

В третьем издании Effective Java (адаптированном под Java 9) Блох рекомендует, если это возможно, использовать интерфейсы и методы по-умолчанию для скелетных реализаций, но при этом отмечает что ограничения интерфейсов могут потребовать использовать абстрактный класс:

> To summarize, an interface is generally the best way to define a type that
>   permits multiple implementations. If you export a nontrivial interface, you
>   should strongly consider providing a skeletal implementation to go with it. **To
>   the extent possible, you should provide the skeletal implementation via default
>   methods on the interface so that all implementors of the interface can make use
>   of it.** That said, restrictions on interfaces typically mandate that a skeletal
>   implementation take the form of an abstract class.

До Java 8 было несколько физических ограничений, из-за которых нельзя было использовать интерфейс:

1. методы интерфейса не могли содержать реализацию (неактульно после появления методов по-умолчанию в Java 8);
2. в интерфейсе нельзя было объявить private-методы (неактуально с Java 9);
3. в интерфейсе нельзя было объявить нестатичные поля.

Сейчас такое ограничение осталось только одно.

### Логические причины

Кроме физических ограничений могут быть еще логические (философские) причины использовать абстрактный класс. Методы в скелетной реализации могут быть пустыми, выбрасывать исключения и содержать неочевидный код, который подойдет только для определенных случаев. Это имеет смысл если части наследников класса эти методы не понадобятся, так они смогут сэкономить на коде.

<strike>Методы же по-умолчанию чисто субъективно воспринимаются как методы интерфейса, которые не нужно переопределять. Ожидается, что они будут содержать достаточно очевидный код, который будет обращаться к другим методам интерфейса. Если прописывать в них пустую реализацию или выбрасывать исключения это может привести к ошибкам.</strike>

**Пример:** в классе [`AbstractCollection`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java) нет нестатичных полей. При этом разработчики все равно решили использовать абстрактный класс, а не «выносить» все методы в интерфейс (большинство методов [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) не default).

Частично это решение обусловлено инерцией: нет причин радикально изменять старый класс от которого зависят миллионы других. Но есть и логические причины. Например, метод `add` в скелетной реализации выбрасывает исключение:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Так, коллекции, которые не поддерживают добавление элементов могут наследоваться от `AbstractCollection` без необходимости прописывать «лишние» методы.

Объявлять `add` как default в `Collection` было бы нецелесообразно. Разработчик, который будет использовать именно интерфейс, а не скелетный класс:

```
class MyCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
...
}
```

скорее всего захочет получить предупреждение о необходимости переопределения `add` и сам принять решение о его поведении. Если `add` будет по-умолчанию выбрасывать исключение, то это приведет к ошибке на стадии тестирования, а не на стадии компиляции, что нежелательно.

**Обновление:** Нашел контрпример: [`Iterator.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) который и default и бросает исключение. Да и Brian Goetz [утверждает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684917), что использовать методы по-умолчанию как необязательные — это нормально.

Получается что при отсутствии нестатичных полей выбор между default методом и реализацией в абстрактном классе чисто субъективен. Если разработчики по каким-то причинам считают что большинству клиентов интерфейса понадобится переопределить метод то имеет смысл реализовать его в абстрактном классе. Если наоборот, то реализовать в самом интерфейсе как default.

Comment: А зачем реализовывать add(), если его можно просто оставить на реализацию."Скорее всего захочет получить предупреждение о необходимости переопределения add". Или это сделано затем, чтобы можно было реализовывать не все методы(если некоторый функционал тупо не нужен)?

Comment: Вы согласны с этим утверждением: "Когда в методах(даже если мы оставляем его на реализацию) предполагается использование своей для каждого объекта переменной, то нужно использовать abstract class. Если мы не можем утверждать, что с набором объявленных static final переменных мы можем реализовать ВСЕ методы, то нельзя использовать interface. Нужно использовать абстрактный класс. "?

Comment: @Miron Да именно чтобы не реализовывать все методы. Я поправил ответ, судя по всему если нет нестатичных полей, то разница между двумя подходами субъективная и очень тонкая.

Comment: @Miron В общем согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, с возникнованием *default методов* в интерфейсах появилось много неразбирихи и разница между абстрактными классами и интерфейсами стала тоньше.

Нужно понимать для чего были созданы *default методы*. Главная причина их появления - это обратная совместимость. Хотели расширить интерфейсы стандартной библиотеки без поломки существующего кода.

Так же при использовании *default методов* у вас нет состояния, т.к. интерфейс может хранить только `static` переменные. Помимо этого есть еще ряд ограничений, вроде невозможности определения `private` методов (в дальнейших релизах java это убрали) и пр.

Принимая в учет вышесказанное, я больше склоняюсь к использования абстрактных классов в таких случаях.

Comment: Так правильно ли это утверждение - "Учитывая факт того, что интерфейсы имеют кл. слово default получается, что абстрактные классы используются для тех случаев, когда нужны изменяемые(не final, как в интерфейсах) переменные, КОТОРЫЕ ВЗАИМОДЕЙСТВУЮТ(меняют значение) в абстрактных методах(или при реализации это предполагается)"?

Comment: тут даже не в final дело. В интерфейсе вы можете объявить только public static final, что не является заменой полноценного состояния которое может храниться в абстрактном классе. Конечно все специфично, но лучше всегда использовать абстрактные классы, если есть какая то иерархия классов и общий код

Comment: Предпочтительнее когда вы хотите сохранить обратную совместимость, так же, когда хотите сделать "множественное наследование". С абстрактными классами так не получится а вот с интерфейсами да

Comment: Я понял. Ведь должен быть public STATIC final. То есть это одна переменная на весь класс. А когда в методах(даже если мы оставляем его на реализацию) предполагается использование своей для каждого объекта переменной, то нужно использовать abstract class. Правильно?

Comment: Если мы не можем утверждать, что с набором объявленных static final переменных мы можем реализовать ВСЕ методы, то нельзя использовать interface. Нужно использовать абстрактный класс. Так?

Comment: @Miron если коротко да. и это тоже